# How to pluck a value from foreach statement in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.6

I am getting an array from database table and through a for each statement. Then check the difference between two values if there is any difference that is less than zero sets a value to 0 for that loop. Then do the same with the next loop.

```php
$bom_id = App\Models\Bom::where('item_id', $item->order_item->id)->pluck('id')->first();
if ($bom_id > 0) {
    $bomList = App\Models\Bom_list::where('bom_id', $bom_id)->get();
    echo '<div class="row">';

    foreach ($bomList as $bomlist) {
        $availableQty = $item->order_item->qty;
        $requiredQty = $bomlist->qty * $item->qty;
        $dif = $availableQty - $requiredQty;
    }

    $check = '';
    $arr = array($bomlist->$dif);
    $light = in_array($check, $arr, true) ? 0 : 1;
} else {
    $light = 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSOLB.png)

Comment: Check whether in each loop has any component with a less than zero

Comment: What is your question?